# When updating SharePoint profile in Delve, where are the preset 'skills' stored?

Tags: user-profile

Apologies that I need to be asking this question but I have not managed to find the answer/question anywhere.

I am updating my profile in Delve and i'm only allowed to enter certain keywords into the 'skills' section. While I can easily live with this, when it comes to asking to business to populate their profiles, I am certain I will get asked this question many times.

Is this preset list in a term-store somewhere? Can I change a setting to allow users to enter new keywords?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Skills are a property of the User Profile stored in the SharePoint Admin center. Go to user profiles, and select Manage user profiles link

[image]

search for your profile, and select to edit it. In the skills section, you'd see your added skills which reflects the ones added in Delve.

[image]

Delve

[image]

Users should be able to add Keyword, Job Title or any other property not connected to Keyword or Job Title.